# Sub-criteria code for multiple decision makers in ahp package

Tags: r, process, yaml, hierarchy

I'd like to create a crieria (Fun) with two sub-criteria (Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity) for 3 multiple decision (Dad, Mom and Kid) in a yaml file for my AHP hierarchy tree using ahp package, but doesn't work. In ahp File Format Elements (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ahp/vignettes/file-format.html) the elements were:

```
criteria 1
  preferences
  childrend
    sub-criteria 1.1
    sub-criteria 1.2
      children: *alternatives
```

But, when I try:

```
Fun:
  preferences:
    Dad:
      pairwise
      - [Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity, 1/5]
    Mom:
      pairwise
      - [Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity, 1/5]  
    Kid:
      pairwise
      - [Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity, 1/5]  
  childrend:
    Cargo Capacity: 
      preferences:
        Dad:
          pairwise:
          - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 3]
          - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
          - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
        Mom:
          pairwise:
          - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
          - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
          - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
        Kid:
          pairwise:
            - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
            - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 1]
            - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]  
    Passenger Capacity: 
      preferences:
        Dad:
          pairwise:
          - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
          - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
          - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
        Mom:
          pairwise:
          - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 5]
          - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
          - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 9]
        Kid:
          pairwise:
          - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
          - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 5]
          - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
      children: *alternatives
```

Error was a duplicate map key:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Could not load ahp model. File must be a valid YAML file. Exception caught when parsing YAML file: Error in yaml::yaml.load(ahpString): Duplicate map key: 'Kid'
```

and If I remove the "Kid", then "Mom" is duplicated.
How can I fix this? Because I expected one value for each sub-criteria and 3 values inside each sub criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your file:

1. you spaces/indentation are misaligned in many places. If you use the editor at http://ipub.com/apps/ahp/, it will help you to align, and also lets you use tab key to indent without thinking.
2. You need a Version element at the beginning
3. Next, you need an Alternatives section, with alternative objects in it
4. Your goal section needs to be called Goal
5. You need to be very careful with the colon in YAML: whenever you have an object, make sure to use : (e.g. after pairwise)
6. for each node in your decision tree, you need to add a children section
7. for each leaf in your decision tree, you need to add the alternatives into the children section

A file that works (which is very similar to the one at the end of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ahp/vignettes/file-format.html) is:

`Version: 2.0
Alternatives: &alternatives
    Fipronil:
        description: alternative 1
    Imidaclopride:
        description: alternative 2
    Sulfluramida:
        description: alternative 3
Goal:
    name: Fun
    decision-makers:
        - Dad: 1/3
        - Mom: 1/3
        - Kid: 1/3
    preferences:
        Dad:
            pairwise:
                - [Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity, 1/5]
        Mom:
            pairwise:
                - [Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity, 1/5]

        Kid:
            pairwise:
                - [Cargo Capacity, Passenger Capacity, 1/5]

    children:
        Cargo Capacity: 
            preferences:
                Dad:
                  pairwise:
                  - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 3]
                  - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
                  - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
                Mom:
                  pairwise:
                  - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
                  - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
                  - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
                Kid:
                  pairwise:
                    - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
                    - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 1]
                    - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
            children: *alternatives
        Passenger Capacity: 
            preferences:
                Dad:
                    pairwise:
                        - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
                        - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
                        - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
                Mom:
                    pairwise:
                        - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 5]
                        - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 9]
                        - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 9]
                Kid:
                    pairwise:
                        - [Fipronil, Imidaclopride, 7]
                        - [Fipronil, Sulfluramida, 5]
                        - [Imidaclopride, Sulfluramida, 5]
            children: *alternatives`

Again, the easiest way to play around is the editor in the shiny app (see link above). Simply paste it and off you go...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your indentation is faithful to your original, or that you are using TAB characters in your YAML file (you should not do that).

Your `preferences:` key has no value, if it should have a mapping with `Dad` as one of the keys, make sure it is indented further than `preferences`, it currently is not.

The problem is that the key `childrend` has a value that is a mapping and that mapping has keys: `Cargo Capacity`, `Dad`, `Mom`, `Kid`, `Passenger Capacity`, `Dad`, `Mom`, `Kid`. And double keys are not allowed.

Comment: Hi Anthon, thanks but I'm don't use TAB only space. But I need a decision for Cargo Capacity e other for Passanger Capacity, like a famous car exemple, were there are Capacity criteria with two sub-criteria Cargo Capacity and Passanger Capacity. The only diference in my example was multiple decision makers.